# Python keystroke detection

Tags: python

I am attempting to let the user input "I agree" in the textbox I have created. However, I want any key entered to be a specific key I have set. An example is "I agree". If I hit any key besides backspace or enter, it will type out I, if I hit another it will do the space, you get the idea.

Comment: What do you mean by textbox? What GUI library are you using? Is this a command line program or GUI?

Comment: I should have specified the program I'm using is renpy. 

This is supposed to be a gui that prompts the user with a warning before asking them to type "I agree" to continue. I already have a true-false statement to close the game if entered while empty and to proceed if "I agree" has been typed out. What I want is for every and any key the user presses to be detected and instead of it entering the said key, it types out one part of "I agree"
Such as if I hit A, it types I in the input box, etc.

Comment: I don’t have experience with that library, but you can try using keyboard hooks (try pyhook) to intercept keyboard events.

Comment: Details in your question, please, not in comments.